# node express) I am confronting with this problem

Tags: node.js

I am making todo list. I am trying to show the list from the database(mySQL) but this problem has come to me.

[image]

The above is the error:

From now on, this is possibly where the error occurred:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Please, don't paste images. Copy your code and errors directly on the post.

Answer (score 0):

you should return the row inside createTodo function :)